# Why isn't my delete_via_redirect test working in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, testunit

I can't get my logout test to work, yet it works in the browser. I cannot see anything wrong.

```
  test "logout user" do
    chloe = login(:starrychloe, 'passpasspass')
    chloe.delete_via_redirect "/users/logout"
    chloe.assert_equal '/', chloe.path
    chloe.assert_equal "Logged out!", chloe.flash.notice, chloe.flash.to_a
    chloe.assert_select '.button' do |elem|
      puts elem
    end
    chloe.assert_select '.button', 'Login'
```

Here is the error. It still thinks it is logged in, even though the session was destroyed and the `user_id` is no longer in the session:

```
Started DELETE "/users/logout" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-31 23:28:17 -0400
Processing by UsersController#logout as HTML
******************** {"session_id"=>"174289eb62bf8679db7f7b04e28c0822", "invalidLogin"=>0, "user_id"=>1, "flash"=>{"discard"=>["notice"], "flashes"=>{"notice"=>"Logged in! Last seen from 172.196.66.44."}}, "_csrf_token"=>"iKYW4LJvZU/1jrw7P6nnZho2ePms3uDde4EH/y5bRjM="}
******************** {"session_id"=>"7dbc9379256566a5bb642c91a9301501"}
Redirected to http://www.example.com:443/
Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-31 23:28:17 -0400
Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 6.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
<div class="button"><a href="/">All</a></div>
<div class="button"><a data-method="delete" href="/users/logout" rel="nofollow">Logout</a></div>
F

  1) Failure:
UserFlowsTest#test_logout_user [test/integration/user_flows_test.rb:43]:
<Login> expected but was
<All>..
Expected 0 to be >= 1.

1 runs, 0 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Here is the controller method

```
  def logout
puts "******************** #{session.to_hash}"    
    reset_session
puts "******************** #{session.to_hash}"    
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged out!"
```

I recently changed it from `method: :post` to `method: :delete`. I also tried `redirect_to :root` but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found another bug in Rails. I added `puts chloe.response.body` and saw that it was printing the correct non-logged in page, but for some reason, assert_select was still using the page from before! I fixed the problem by creating a new HTML::Document element from the response.body and selecting on that text directly.

```
puts chloe.response.body
doc = HTML::Document.new chloe.response.body
chloe.assert_select doc.root, '.button' do |elem|
  puts elem
end
chloe.assert_select doc.root, '.button', 'Login'
```

Now it correctly lists the links that a new user would see

```
<div class="button"><a href="/">All</a></div>
<div class="button"><a data-no-turbolink="true" href="/users/login">Login</a></div>
<div class="button"><a data-no-turbolink="true" href="/users/new">Register</a></div>
```

Here is the issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/15454

Comment: Found exactly the same bug while following M. Hartl's Rails tutorial. I'll take a look and see if I can submit a patch. Thanks for documenting!